# Fedora 33 git pull or clone no longer working and/or ssh key no longer recognized

Tags: git, ssh, fedora

I recently set up Fedora 33 and was migrating over my files. I copied over my ssh keys and found that I could no longer pull from bitbucket git repos I was able to pull from on my old laptop. The ssh keys are exactly the same, and the public key is already on the bitbucket account. Additionally the permissions were set to `chmod 600`. I still can not pull from the repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper solution: use `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and copy that public key into your bitbucket account.

Comment: I only use ed25519 keys and still Bitbucket started complaining after updating OpenSSH to 8.8. It does really seem they only support legacy key types on their servers (ssh-rsa,ssh-dss).

Answer (score 26):

This seems to be a recent issue around Fedora 33. This is the relevant [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1884920).

The issue is that it seems like Fedora 33 removed support for `SHA1`, and I guess `bitbucket.org` uses `SHA1` for their `git clone` via `ssh`. You can verify if this is the same issue by running `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` and `grep` the output for `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm`.

The current workaround, as listed in the bug report, is to explicitly specify `ssh-rsa` support in your `~/.ssh/config`:

Add the following entry to your `~/.ssh/config` and make sure it has the permission `chmod 700 ~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket.org
    User git
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
```

Replace `bitbucket.org` with whatever git host you are using

Comment: That's not what `bitbucket` uses, it's what you choose when creating your keypair.

Comment: The issue is also present in cygwin and fixed like shown in this answer

Comment: Just switched from Centos 8 to Fedors 34 and ran into this exact issue.  I like the idea of using `~/.ssh/conifg` to turn SHA1 back on for jjust this one site.