# Git not using SSH Key to authenticate to Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, git, azure, github, ssh

I recently switched to a new install of Fedora 33 Silverblue running a toolbox. This also happened outside of the toolbox as well. I generated an SSH key using the following command

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C filbot@fenix
```

Then I uploaded it to Azure DevOps under my account. However, I cannot clone anything from Azure DevOps with the following `~/.ssh/config`:

```
⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
# SSH Configuration File
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
  HostName ssh.dev.azure.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/home/filbot/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  HostName vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/home/filbot/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then I ran these `git clone` commands with the following result:

```sh
⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/$ORG/$PROJ/Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks
Cloning into 'Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks'...
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password: 

⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/$ORG/$PROJ/Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks
Cloning into 'Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks'...
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password: 

⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '20.37.158.9' to the list of known hosts.
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password: 

⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
```

It seems that Git is not respecting or even using the ssh config in my home directory like it did before or in other older installs of Fedora or Pop!_OS. I don't understand why it's doing this now, and how to get the information to figure this out more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and found a solution here:

[Fedora 33 git pull or clone no longer working and/or ssh key no longer recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792380/fedora-33-git-pull-or-clone-no-longer-working-and-or-ssh-key-no-longer-recognize)

Basically, in your `~/.ssh/config` file, under each `Host` section, add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa`.

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
  HostName ssh.dev.azure.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/home/filbot/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Run ssh in debug mode, with -v. It will output the whole process running in the background. In the output, it will mention what method of authentication it's using and why.

Comment: It's in debug mode, it had show a lot. Would you mind sharing the output?

Comment: When I used `git clone -v $url`, it still only showed the login.

Comment: Try ssh -vv, this will output the authentications that are available.

Comment: Still nothing. I cannot paste the output becasue it's too long and loses formatting. It still just drops to the prompt for the credentials. @Matt S. answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Fedora 33 thing. I used a Fedora 32 Toolbox and Git worked as expected.

```sh
➜  ~ toolbox create --release f32
Image required to create toolbox container.
Download registry.fedoraproject.org/f32/fedora-toolbox:32 (500MB)? [y/N]: y
Created container: fedora-toolbox-32
Enter with: toolbox enter --release 32
➜  ~ toolbox enter --release 32
⬢[filbot@toolbox ~]$ git clone -v git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/$ORG/$PROJ/Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks
Cloning into 'Developer.dudleyp.cs_pipeline_tasks'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 45 objects to send. (88 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (45/45), 77.83 KiB | 25.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (14/14), done.
```