# Fedora 33: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, git, ssh, bitbucket, fedora

I am trying to setup ssh for my bitbucket following [this](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) official tutorial, however at the last step of troubleshooting the connection I get following

`git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

here is the output of `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i FIPS  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_c123b90d72-dirty conker-3003
debug1: no match: conker_c123b90d72-dirty conker-3003
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:<random symbols>
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<random symbols>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jiraichi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<random symbols> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/jiraichi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<random symbols> agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

really stuck here, any help appreciated

Comment: And none of the [pages full](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk003fH7z9DBmMC2zS5KaxTIxrPtraw%3A1613080590524&ei=DqglYI-_H-fYz7sPo7O24A8&q=bitbucket.org%3A+%22ssh+-T%22+Permission+denied+%28publickey%29+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=bitbucket.org%3A+%22ssh+-T%22+Permission+denied+%28publickey%29+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1DdyCNYluEjYI_sI2gBcAJ4AIAB9gGIAd0OkgEFMC44LjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiP_t286eLuAhVn7HMBHaOZDfwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) of links with the same problem shed light on your issue?

Comment: I am still researching, but so far nothing helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Apparently inserting this line `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` into my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` solved the problem, I am running Fedora 33</del>

<del>however I am still not sure whether this solution introduces any security risks.</del>

<del>edit: found a better (more clean I would say) solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792380/fedora-33-git-pull-or-clone-no-longer-working-and-or-ssh-key-no-longer-recognize/64792381#64792381), apparently it is a known bug of Fedora 33 and currently workaround should be used.</del>

update: as pointed in the comments correct solution is using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and copy that public key into your bitbucket account.

Comment: You say it's a bug, but I would encourage you to consider it as Fedora disallowing weak crypto. You should upgrade your ssh keys so they are stronger and better protect your communication. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2#Detailed_Description for more information.

Comment: Well ... that's one way of going about it.  The proper way would be to generate a key-pair with a stronger hashing algorithm; That, of course, would deviate from the "tutorial", which encourages one to use the weak default RSA.  Proper solution: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and copy **that** public key into your bitbucket account.

Comment: my apologies and thank you for your input, learned few new things

Answer (score -2):

Your input contains an error. Remove the 'v' next to '-T'. It should be like this:

ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

Comment: Ummmm .... no. The -v just generates verbose output, it doesn't cause the failure.